# Change actionbar background from Dialog Activity

Tags: android, styles, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-dialog

I'm making a Activity Dialog and want to customize the layout of the Activity.
I already had set in the manifest the custom style by my activity which extends `"@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"`.

If I use `<item name="android:windowTitleStyle">CUSTOM_STYLE_NAME</item>` the only change of backgroundcolor is behind the title and not the whole actionbar.

Setting `<item name="android:actionBarStyle">` in my custom style didn't help either.

So how can I change the background of my actionbar in my Activity Dialog?

[image]

Comment: apply a dialog theme to activity and use it like a dialog

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302449/android-change-custom-dialog-title-background

Comment: Hi Raghunandan thanks for the response, but the problem is that I have a dialog theme with an actionbar, and if I style the windowTitleStyle, only the background of the text will be get the color and not the whole titlebar/actionbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425020/actionbar-in-a-dialogfragment) tweak I found on stackoverflow.
What you basically do is to declare your own dialog style which you add to your activity as theme:

```
<style name="PopupTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateAlwaysHidden</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```

---

Than declare in your oncreate the follow method:

```
public static void showAsPopup(Activity activity) {
   //To show activity as dialog and dim the background, you need to declare   android:theme="@style/PopupTheme" on for the chosen activity on the manifest
  activity.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
  activity.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
  LayoutParams params = activity.getWindow().getAttributes(); 
  params.height = 850; //fixed height
  params.width = 850; //fixed width
  params.alpha = 1.0f;
  params.dimAmount = 0.5f;
  activity.getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params); 
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

After this you can add your own custom actionbar style with the background color of your choice:

```
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
```

ps. LayoutParams is from WindowManager

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see your custom style XML so, I guess you set textbackground instead of backgrondcolor..

Comment: Hi Esmaeel, no I already use backgroundcolor, only the style parent is android:Widget.TextView